# how to insert title tag into the img tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code to insert the title to all the img but it doesn't seem to work .

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


           $('img').attr('title','my title value');


      });
```

Jquery is properly working and shows all the insert and other operations but only this task i am stuck and don't know how to best accomplish it.

Comment: [Works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/arFXF/)

Comment: It's [working](http://jsfiddle.net/zDuq8/) for me.

Comment: Can I assume that all of the blank lines in your code are where you removed code to simplify the above? Perhaps the other code is changing the `img`s or is exiting the method...

Comment: What `DOCTYPE` are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain its not working? Have you viewed the generated source to see the title attribute not there?

If your just testing it by hovering your mouse over the image then it may not show if you have an alt tag specified.

Also what version of jQuery are you running?

Comment: i am using jquery-1.5.1.min.js, and when i view source not a single img has title

Comment: Viewing the source (in the traditional way, at least) wouldn't show a modification made by JavaScript.

Comment: In firefox higlight the whole page (Ctrl + A) then right click and select 'view selection source' to see the modified HTML.

Comment: it was working from the first time and thanks for the comment i did not knew the view source does not show modifications made by javascript.